# I don't understand why my google scripts script isn't working

Tags: google-apps-script

I've recently started using google scripts for google sheets and I can't get my onEdit function to work
this is my code:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var range = event.range;
  var spreadsheet = event.source;
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var activesheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var column = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var spreadsheetname = activesheet.getName();
  var D5LOC = activesheet.getRange("D5").getValue();
  activesheet.getRange("D3").setValue(D5LOC);
  
  if(D5LOC == "FALSE"){
    activesheet.getRange("D6").setValue(activesheet.getRange("D5").getValue());
    if (!(column == 1)&&!(column == 2)&&event.value == "FALSE")
    {
        activesheet.getRange("D6").setValue(activesheet.getRange("D5").getValue());
        r.setValue("TRUE");

    }
  }
}
```

It's supposed to check every box that I've unchecked whenever a confirmation box is unchecked, however when I uncheck something it just doesn't do anything. please help

Comment: Welcome to [so]. The question doesn't include enough details as we don't know the structure of your spreadsheet. Please edit the question to add more details. P.S. When using `getValue` to get the value of a checkbox the returned value is a boolean not a string. If D5 has a checkbox you have to use `false` instead of `"FALSE"`.

Comment: It's easy to fix if you would explain what it is that you wish is to do a little better.   An image of your sheet might be helpful.

Comment: I've moved the following advice from the answer below into this comment: _If you can provide me with a better description of what you wish it to do then  I can help.  An image of your sheet may be helpful and please note I will not follow links to offsite resources.  If you want me to help you have to post everything in the question._

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell this seems to be what your code currently boils down to:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const D5LOC = sh.getRange("D5").getValue();
  if (sh.getName() == 'Sheet1' && e.range.columnStart > 2 && D5LOC == "FALSE" && e.value == "FALSE") {
    sh.getRange("D3").setValue(D5LOC);
    sh.getRange("D6").setValue(D5LOC);
    e.range.setValue("TRUE")
  }
}
```

Comment: It's worth omitting commentary about the question from answers, because answers are for a wide audience that happens to include the question author. I'll add your advice to a comment. (It seems to be very good advice, it just doesn't belong in an answer).